# Can't run orderer node(Hyperledger fabric)

Tags: shell, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I setting 4 VM(`Ubuntu 18.04`) on Windows10 for running of `Hyperledger fabric`.

The network configuration consist of `Orderer`,`Peer0(Org0)`,`Peer1(Org1)`,`Client` as node on each VM.

Both `peer0` and `peer1` node was successful for running. But, `Orderer` was failed to run. The `Orderer`node seems to be worked properly, but it was not.

I checked `orderer ip`. It was correct.

I used same `orderer.yaml`, `core.yaml` from `Hyperledger fabric sample config.

## runOrderer.sh

```
ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug \
ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=orderer \
ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file \
ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/home/jk/test/testnet/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer/orderers/orderer.orderer/genesis.block \
ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP \
ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/home/jk/test/testnet/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer/orderers/orderer.orderer/msp \
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=false \
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/home/jk/test/testnet/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer/orderers/orderer.orderer/tls/server.key \
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/home/jk/test/testnet/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer/orderers/orderer.orderer/tls/server.crt \
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/home/jk/test/testnet/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer/orderers/orderer.orderer/tls/ca.crt,/home/jk/test/testnet/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0/peers/peer0.org0/tls/ca.crt,/home/jk/test/testnet/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/peers/peer1.org1/tls/ca.crt] \
CONFIGTX_ORDERER_BATCHTIMEOUT=1s \
CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ORDERERTYPE=solo \
orderer
```

## Log

```
2019-05-09 09:36:47.761 KST [orderer/commmon/multichannel] NewRegistrar -> INFO 0b7 Starting system channel 'test-system-channel-name' with genesis block hash 6e0081b164e2cf4b7850577f0172ec6dc16eec227022f7be08db8f4a82b85888 and orderer type solo
2019-05-09 09:36:47.761 KST [orderer/common/server] Start -> INFO 0b8 Starting orderer:
 Version: 1.3.1
 Commit SHA: 546697782
 Go version: go1.12.5
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Experimental features: false
2019-05-09 09:36:47.761 KST [orderer/common/server] Start -> INFO 0b9 Beginning to serve requests
```

It seems to be work, but I knew that was not. I think the `runOrderer.sh` does not work.